# new window in visual force page

Tags: visualforce

My problem is when click on link, the new window takes up the existing window.

My requirement is when click on link, the new window just pop up as tab, without taking up the exisitng window. So that user won't feel distrubed.

```
<apex:outputLink value="#" onclick="return goToAnotherPage('{!studentId}');">
```

In JS,

```
window.location = '/apex/VF_AnotherPage?studentId=' + studentId;
```

How can I make a new window , without taking up the existing window. I need to pass Parameters too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/VF_AnotherPage?studentId={!studentId}" target="_blank">
```

The target="_blank" will open a new window .

In javascript

```
window.open('/apex/VF_AnotherPage?studentId=' + studentId);
```

By default window.open has name parameter as _blank.

Comment: Mohith, I would recommend that you avoid using w3schools (see [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)), and instead quote directly from MSDN or MDN instead.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.The site is not recommended is what i understand from the w3fools .

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return window.open('/apex/VF_AnotherPage?studentId=' + studentId);" >SomeText</a>
```

OR in JS

```
window.open('/apex/VF_AnotherPage?studentId=' + studentId);
```